# Convert a static ui project to a yeoman structure for angualrjs

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, yeoman-generator-angular

I have an existing project which is being written in a standard static project structure. I need to convert the project to a Yeoman project. The current project is written in angular and requirejs.
The structure is as below.

```
- Project
  - karma
  - node_modules
  - src
    - app
    - assets
    - common
    - less
    - service
    - index.html
  - vendor
```

The app folder consists of subfolders for each module on the page within which is the controller ,html and less file for that particular module.

Any help would be appreciated as i have just 2 days to do this and i am not sure how i can restructure the code.

Comment: you can call yo angular and then start to move your files in the new structure

Comment: If i move the existing app folder to the yeoman app folder would it work directly?

Comment: maybe, but it's very difficult, for sure you will have some path issues

Answer (score 0):

If you have modular structure then you should definately go with [angular-gulp-generator](https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular).

Angular gulp generator use such a similar structure for projects. All you have to do is put your code into new structure and then let generator make its magic...

Angular gulp generator automatically inject all js files into your index.html and if you choose less as a style processor will do same thing for all less files under src folder...

Comment: Should i generate the structure and then copy the files manually into the structure? And also what is the difference between the angular generator in yeoman and the gulp generator?

Comment: yes do it like that first create new project with angular-gulp generator then move your file to that projects

Comment: Okay. Let me try with this and get back to you. Thanks